# Can't trigger self-made Event.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this prototype function:

```
Event.prototype.eventPreventDefault = function () {
    this.preventDefault ? this.preventDefault() : this.returnValue = false;
}
```

I call from code by doing this:

```
$element.click(function (evt) {
        evt.eventPreventDefault();
}
```

but I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event objects created by jQuery (and passed into event handlers) are not children of native Events (*'prefer composition over inheritance' principle*). They have [**their own set of methods**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b807aedb7fee321fb3aa5d156a5a256ab0634e2d/src/event.js#L674-L709) (set on `jQuery.Event.prototype`):

```
jQuery.Event.prototype = {
    constructor: jQuery.Event,
    isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse,
    isPropagationStopped: returnFalse,
    isImmediatePropagationStopped: returnFalse,

    preventDefault: function() {
        var e = this.originalEvent;

        this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

        if ( e && e.preventDefault ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    stopPropagation: function() {
        var e = this.originalEvent;

        this.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;

        if ( e && e.stopPropagation ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    },
    // ... and so on.
};
```

As you see, these methods usually call the same-named methods of the original Event (stored in jQuery.Event instance's `originalEvent` property). The point is, `jQuery.Event` doesn't have `Event.prototype` in its inheritance chain, hence any modification of the latter is destined to have no effect on the former.

The bottom line: to extend Events passed into jQuery event handlers, extend `jQuery.Event.prototype` instead of `Event.prototype`.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b807aedb7fee321fb3aa5d156a5a256ab0634e2d/src/event.js#L635-670 for further reading